# Best kiosk mode operation for android self serve kiosk device without android enterprise

Tags: android, android-12, kiosk

As title, whats the best way to keep an app always running in foreground, can't be killed, disable navigation bar without using android enterprise? Android enterprise requires branded enrolled device which is unrealistic for those 24" kiosk devices you see in restaurants.

Comment: You can use Device Policy Controller and manually setup the device owner mode, no need for special branded devices. See https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc

Comment: Alternatively, it may be enough to use the pin screen feature, but it's very limited.